# Add Quartz to a Web API project. Performance question

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, quartz

I need to use Quartz for a time-consuming task to update data in my project, I'm afraid that adding the workers to the web API will limit the performance of the web API when the tasks are running in the background. I'm hosting my web API in Amazon so I can just beef it up or I deploy this project to another server to handle the background jobs in another service.

Hosting the Workers and WebApi on the same server will probably be cheaper. But I know that deploying them separately will make fixes much easier to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm afraid that adding the workers to the web API will limit the performance of the web API when the tasks are running in the background. I'm hosting my web API in Amazon so I can just beef it up or I deploy this project to another server to handle the background jobs in another service.

If your background task would do CPU-intensive or I/O-intensive etc jobs, hosting the Workers and WebApi application(s) on the same server, which might result in resource contention and lead to low performance.

On the other hand, isolating your app (or workers) into separate server (or service) in Amazon, which would take additional charge. You can monitor the metrics of CUP, memory etc usage first, then determine if current hosting approach is ok.